# How can i give a program raw binary byte input which is produced by a different file?

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, character-encoding

I have 2 programs:

`x` - prompts user for input from `stdin`.

`binary` - prints something to `stdout`, the stuff it prints is made up of various raw binary bytes which are not fully supported by my terminals encoding (UTF-8). So i cannot run it normally like `./binary | ./x`, this would result in wrong input being provided to `x` since part of the input consists of `\x90` (NOP) which my terminal replaces with a replacement character.

How can i provide the program `x` with raw binary data produced by another file (in this case `binary`)?

Answer (score 3):

You do it exactly as you described, `./binary | ./x`.  Your terminal gets unhappy with `\x90` characters on input, but that doesn't mean `./x` will.

As a test, you can try `./binary | od -a` and you'll see that a program designed for it can read bytes that give your terminal trouble.  You can also try `od -x` and `od -b` as alternatives to `od -a` (you may prefer those options' methods of representing binary data).